# Setting the MySQL root user password on OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, passwords

I just installed MySQL on Mac OS X. The next step was setting the root user password, so I did this next:

1. Launch the terminal app to access the Unix command line.
2. Under the Unix prompt I executed these commands:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/mysql/bin
   ./mysqladmin -u root password 'password'
   ```

But, when I execute the command

`./mysql -u root`, this is the answer:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 224
Server version: 5.5.13 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I can get into the `mysql` command line without any password!

Why is this?

Answer (score 354):

Try the command `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` when you log into the MySQL terminal.  If that doesn't work, try the following set of commands while in the MySQL terminal

```
mysql -u root

mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit
```

Change out NEWPASSWORD with whatever password you want.  Should be all set!

**Update**: As of MySQL 5.7, the `password` field has been renamed `authentication_string`.  When changing the password, use the following query to change the password.  All other commands remain the same:

```
mysql> UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") WHERE User='root';
```

for MySQL 8.0+ Don't use

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='password' WHERE User='root';
```

as it overwrites the `authentication_string`, which is supposed to be a hash and not plain text, instead use:

```
mysql> `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';`
```

Comment: In MySQL 5.7 onwards, the column name has changed.  You will need to use `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I'll edit my answer to reflect accordingly.

Comment: It also looks like the PASSWORD() function is deprecated and you should just put the `'password'` on the right side of the equality

Comment: If you cannot log in though, how does this help?

Comment: The original question assumed you could log in after a fresh installation, not regaining lost access to a server.

Comment: `ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

Comment: In mysql 8.0 the command is
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';`

Comment: after following these steps. When I tried to login again with my new password I get
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: I think the instructions have changed. This worked for me: `ALTER USER ‘username’@‘localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘newpassword’;`

Comment: @KingstonChan In msql ver 8+ Do you happen to know what I should do if I used `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='password' WHERE User='root';` instead of `ALTER USER ‘username’@‘localhost’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’;`? Because now I got`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: PASSWORD function does no work anymore. This linked answer worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63716361/276263

Answer (score 208):

If you don't remember the password you set for root and need to reset it, follow these steps:

1. Stop the mysqld server, this varies per install
2. Run the server in safe mode with privilege bypass

   `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables;`
3. In a new window connect to the database, set a new password and flush the permissions & quit:

   `mysql -u root`

   For MySQL older than MySQL 5.7 use:

   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('your-password') WHERE User='root';`

   For MySQL 5.7+ use:

   `USE mysql;`

   `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("your-password") WHERE User='root';`

   Refresh and quit:

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

   `\q`
4. Stop the safe mode server and start your regular server back. The new password should work now. It worked like a charm for me :)

---

**Note**

Run
`UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';`
if you don't want to set a password for root user. Or if `PASSWORD()` function doesn't work for you.

Comment: That was perfect thank you!  On Mac OSx Mavericks (2014) use  sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop|start|restart

Comment: `password` need to be `authentication_string` now.

Comment: After MySQL 5.7, it should be `UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") WHERE User='root';` , just like @Scott said.

Comment: I needed to have `use mysql;` before `UPDATE user…` or I received an error about selecting the database. Otherwise worked well, thanks.

Comment: On MacOSx when mySQL is installed with the "Preference "Pane" option (Apple Menu -> System Preferences...), i found that I first had to stop mySQL using the preference pane to complete step 1 of the above.  Using `sudo kill` did not work as the Mac OSx would automatically relaunch a new msql instantly.  Once I stopped mysql using the preference pane, I could manually run `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

Comment: please use `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables;` instead of `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` if you forget the semi-coma the daemon will not end correctly

Comment: @radtek hey i can change it but when `mysqlld_Safe` stops executing then it doesn't work anymore

Comment: On macos big sur with mysql installed with homebrew steps worked this way:
`
1. brew services stop mysql@5.7
2. mysqld --skip-grant-tables
`
notice that step two worked without sudo or mysqld_safe (this actually didn't want to start at all)

Answer (score 88):

Once you've installed MySQL, you'll need to establish the "root" password. If you don't establish a root password, then, well, there is no root password, and you don't need a password to log in.

So, that being said, you need to establish a root password.

Using terminal enter the following:

### Installation: Set root user password:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password NEW_PASSWORD_HERE
```

If you've made a mistake, or need to change the root password use the following:

### Change root password:

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/
./mysql -u root -p
> Enter password: [type old password invisibly]

use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW_PASSWORD_HERE") where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit
```

Comment: For those who have MySQL 5.7, you should use `update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("NEW_PASSWORD_HERE") where User='root';` instead of using `set password=...`

Comment: If you installed mysql with brew then you might need to replace `/usr/local` with `/opt/homebrew`

Answer (score 81):

The instructions provided in the mysql website is so clear, than the above mentioned

1. `$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`
2. `$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables`
3. `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`
4. mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
5. mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
6. mysql> `exit` or Ctrl + z
7. `$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`
8. `$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`
9. `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql -u root -p`
10. Enter the new password i.e MyNewPass

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: in mac os 10.12.6 , it gives error after 2nd command  *ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/myhostname.pid).*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where to find the documentation. It is a little confusing on the mac when you can also use  sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist and  sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist to stop and  start mysql. Using sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop seems like a better approach.

Answer (score 64):

1. Stop the *mysqld* server.

- **Mac OS X:** *System Preferences* → *MySQL* → *Stop MySQL Server*
- **Linux (From Terminal):** `sudo systemctl stop mysqld.service`

2. Start the server in safe mode with privilege bypass

   - **From Terminal:** `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
3. In a **new** terminal window:

   - `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root`
4. This will open the MySQL command-line client. From here enter:

   - `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('NewPassword') WHERE User='root';`
   - `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
   - `quit`
5. Stop the mysqld server again and restart it in normal mode.

   - **Mac OS X (From Terminal):** `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart`
   - **Linux Terminal:** `sudo systemctl restart mysqld`

Comment: For running  5.7.23 on High Sierra, this works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: In MySQL 8.0.11, the set function in the 4th step was removed. You check here, this one is worked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52579886/621951

Answer (score 27):

For the new MySQL 5.7, for some reason the binary commands of MySQL aren't attached to the shell, and you have to do:

1. Restart the Mac after the installation.
2. Start MySQL:

   *System Preferences* → *MySQL* → *Start button*
3. Go to MySQL install folder in the terminal:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/
   ```
4. Access to MySQL:

   ```
   ./mysql -u root -p
   ```

   And enter the initial password given to the installation.
5. In the MySQL client, change the password:

   `mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPassword';`

Answer (score 15):

In the terminal, write `mysql -u root -p` and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Enter the current MySQL password that you must have noted down.

And set the password:

`SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new_password');`

Please refer to this documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-user.html) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

If you have forgot the MySQL root password, can’t remember or want to break in….. you can reset the MySQL database password from the command line in either Linux or OS X as long as you know the root user password of the box you are on:

(1) Stop MySQL

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

(2) Start it in safe mode:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

(3) This will be an ongoing command until the process is finished **so open another shell/terminal window**, log in without a password:

```
mysql -u root

UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
```

In the UPDATE command above just replace the 'password' with your own new password, make sure to keep the quotation marks

(4) Save and quite

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

\q
```

(5) Start MySQL

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 7):

None of the previous comments solved the issue on my Mac.

I used the commands below and it worked.

```
brew services stop mysql
pkill mysqld
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql/ # NOTE: this will delete your existing database!!!
brew postinstall mysql
brew services restart mysql
mysql -u root
```

Comment: I followed all of your steps and I get the below error
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by:

1. Shutting down my MySQL server: `mysql.server stop`
2. Running MySQL in safe mode: `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
3. In another terminal, login with `mysql -u root`
4. In the same terminal, run `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';`, then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`  and then exit with `exit;`
5. Stop the safe mode server with `mysql.server stop` and then start the normal one; `mysql.server start`

Now you can set your new password with

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';
```

Answer (score 5):

When I installed [OS X v10.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite), I got a problem with MySQL. I tried lot of methods, but none worked.  I actually found a quite easy way. Try this out.

1. First log in to a terminal from super user (su) privileges.

   `sudo su`
2. Stop MySQL

   `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`
3. Start in safe mode:

   `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
4. Open another terminal, log in as su privileges, and then, log in to the MySQL client (`mysql`) without a password

   `mysql -u root`
5. Change the password

   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User='root';`
6. Flush privileges

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
7. You are done now.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I was struggling with this for a bit. Is this a new thing on the latest versions of mysql?

Answer (score 5):

The methods mentioned in existing answers don't work for MySQL 5.7.6 or later. According the MySQL documentation, this is the recommended way.

**B.5.3.2.3 Resetting the Root Password: Generic Instructions**

MySQL 5.7.6 and later:

`mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';`

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 3):

If you can't remember your password, [@radtek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22851247/5274109) worked for me except in my case I had [set up MySQL using brew](https://gist.github.com/nrollr/3f57fc15ded7dddddcc4e82fe137b58e) which meant that steps 1 and 2 of his answer had to be changed to:

1. `/usr/local/bin/mysql.server stop`
2. `/usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

**Note:** the lack of `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

This is what exactly worked for me:

1. Make sure no other MySQL process is running. To check this do the
   following:

   - From the terminal, run this command:

     ```
     lsof -i:3306
     ```

     If any PID is returned, kill it using `kill -9 PID`
   - Go to *System Preferences* → *MySQL* → check if any MySQL instances are running, stop them.
2. Start MySQL with the command:

   ```
   sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
   ```
3. The password for every user is stored in the mysql.user table under columns User and authentication_string respectively. We can update the table as:

   ```
   UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='your_password' where User='root'
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOURNEWPASSWORD'
```

(Note that you should probably replace root with your username if it isn't root.)

Answer (score 2):

### Stopping MySQL Server

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`

### Starting MySQL in safe mode

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

### Changing the root password

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root`

```
use mysql;
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('NEW_PASSWORD') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

### Testing

Run `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root`

Now enter the new password to start using MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

[macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave) and later with 5.7.26 installed from the Mac OS X DMG installer.

When attempting to use the UPDATE command posted by other users, it results in the following error:

> ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.

Copy the password that was presented to you by the *installer*, open a terminal, and do the following:

```
mysql -uroot -p
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOURPASSWORDHERE';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in a terminal:

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Answer (score 2):

This workaround works on my laptop!

Mac with [macOS v10.14.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave).

MySQL 8.0.17 was installed with [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)).

- I run the following command to locate the path of MySQL

  `brew info mysql`
- Once the path is known, I run this:

  `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.17/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-table`
- In another terminal I run:

  `mysql -u root`
- Inside that terminal, I changed the root password using:

  `update mysql.user set authentication_string='NewPassword' where user='root';`
- and to finish I run:

  `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

And voilà, the password was reset.

[References](https://gist.github.com/zubaer-ahammed/c81c9a0e37adc1cb9a6cdc61c4190f52)

Answer (score 2):

To reference MySQL 8.0.15 + , the password() function is not available. Use the command below.

Kindly use

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='password' WHERE User='root';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manually turn-off MySQL on Mac, by clicking on  Apple menu and open *System Preferences*. Choose the “MySQL” preference panel, and then click on the “Stop MySQL Server” button to stop MySQL Server on Mac.

After you stop your MySQL, you'll need to follow these steps.

- You'll need to start MySQL in skip-grant-tables mode

  ```
  sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables
  ```
- In your terminal itself, enter this command to *flush* existing *privileges*

  ```
  /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ```
- Now you need to alter the user password

  ```
  mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';

  mysql> exit
  ```

Then you can go to  Apple menu and open System Preferences. Choose the “MySQL” preference panel, then click on the “Stop MySQL Server” button to stop MySQL Server on Mac.

Finally you can again go to  Apple menu and open System Preferences. Choose the “MySQL” preference panel, then click on the “Start MySQL Server” button to start MySQL Server on Mac.

Comment: fantastic!! it helps me a lot

Comment: Glad it helped you Samiul :)

Answer (score 2):

**For MySQL 8**

1. Shutdown MySQL server

- Go to System Preferences -> MySQL
- Click `Stop MySQL Server` button

2. Open two terminal [command-line] windows
3. In the first terminal window run the following:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

4. In the second terminal window do the following:

4.1. Login to MySQL

```
mysql -u root
```

4.2. Run the following in the MySQL prompt:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NEWPASSWORD';
```

4.3. Exit MySQL

```
exit;
```

5. Go back to the first terminal window and shutdown `mysqld_safe`

5.1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

5.2. Run the following command

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

5.3. Enter the new password you set in `4.2.` when prompted.

6. Start MySQL Server [see `1.`]

Answer (score 1):

If you forgot your password or want to change it to your MySQL:

1. Start your terminal and enter:

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
2. Enter the password for you system
3. Stop your MySQL server:

   ```
   sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
   ```
4. Leave this window *open*, run second terminal window and enter here:

   ```
   mysql -u root
   ```
5. And change your password for MySQL:

   ```
   UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User='root';
   ```

   where "new_password" - your new password. You don't need old password for MySQL.
6. Flush, quit and check your new password:

   ```
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
7. Close all windows and check your new password for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Much has changed for MySQL 8. I've found the following modification of the [MySQL 8.0 "How to Reset the Root Password" documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) works with Mac OS X.

Create a temporary file, `$HOME/mysql.root.txt`, with the SQL to update the root password:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<new-password>';
```

This uses `mysql_native_password` to avoid the [Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded) error, which I get if I omit the option.

Stop the server, start with an `--init-file` option to set the root password, and then restart the server:

```
mysql.server stop
mysql.server start --init-file=$HOME/mysql.root.txt
mysql.server stop
mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin

now,to make this permanent:
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile

next, start mysql in safe mode:
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables;

If this does not work, go to System Preferences and stop MySQL server.
next, On the **other** terminal, you may use the below:

$ mysql -u root

mysql> USE mysql;

mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE 
User='root';

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

mysql> exit;

$ mysql -u root
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 
caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpassword';

$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
mysql> SELECT user();

next, start the mysql server in normal mode. and you're done with resetting your root password. this worked for mysql 8.0.17 ver. for me.
thanks to everyone on top, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099028/error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-want-to-configure-a-pa,
```

[https://www.houseninetytwo.com/how-to-use-mysql-in-terminal-on-mac-os-high-sierra/#:~:text=You%20may%20have%20gotten%20something,%2Fmysql%2Fbin%2Fmysql.&text=It%20should%20execute%20the%20right,return%20your%20version%20of%20MySQL](https://www.houseninetytwo.com/how-to-use-mysql-in-terminal-on-mac-os-high-sierra/#:%7E:text=You%20may%20have%20gotten%20something,%2Fmysql%2Fbin%2Fmysql.&text=It%20should%20execute%20the%20right,return%20your%20version%20of%20MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
mysql -u root
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='yourpasswd' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';
```

I somehow need to do this every time my [MacBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#:%7E:text=B.3.3.2.2%C2%A0Resetting%20the%20Root%20Password%3A%20Unix%20and%20Unix%2DLike%20Systems).

As of Dec 2022, the following works for MySQL 8.0.26 on macOS Big Sur 11.2.3:

1. Go to system preferences > mysql > stop server
2. Open terminal and run:

   ```bash
   mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
   ```
3. Open a new terminal and run:

   ```bash
   mysql -u root
   ```
4. Run:

   ```sql
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'ROOT';
   ```

   - ROOT will be your new password.
5. Run:

   ```sql
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
6. Run:

   ```sql
   exit;
   ```
7. Go to “System Preferences > MySQL > Start Server.”