# MySQL allows connection without password although password is set

Tags: mysql, passwords

I'm setting a MySQL server (actually a Percona server, but that shouldn't matter) and I'm setting a password to the root user. At the end, I have this:

```
mysql> select host, user, password from user;
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user             | password                                  |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root             | *huge string here, no kidding             |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint | *another huge string here                 |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I thought this should not allow the root user to connect without a password. However, if I go to the command line, I can connect with `mysql -u root` or just `mysql`. If I do `mysql -u root -p` and hit enter for the password, then I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO).`

Could anyone explain to me how to make sure a user can only connect with a password?

Edit: if relevant, I set the password with `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('somethinghere');`

Edit: output of `show grants`, it indicates I used a password to login but I did not.

```
mysql> show grants;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*huge string here, no kidding' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Did you do a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` in MySQL after setting the password? You can also try doing `mysqladmin -u root reload` and `mysqladmin -u root refresh` (no password since that's how it seems to want to work at the moment).

Comment: yes, I do a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` right after setting them. I ran these two commands you mentioned and nothing changed

Comment: Hmm... if none of that is working, can you just restart MySQL and see if that makes a difference? Not sure what Percona uses for that, but in Debian you do a `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` and in CentOS/RHEL you do `sudo service mysqld restart`

Comment: I've also tried a restart (Ubuntu box), still the same.

Comment: Ok, let's look at how you tried to set the password then. The way I do it is with: `sudo mysqladmin -u root password 'test'` assuming I wanted a stupid password of just test - What did you use to set it?

Comment: Try to understand which account is used, execute SHOW GRANTS query.

Comment: @MarkOrmston Edited the question with the way the password was set

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474775/setting-the-mysql-root-user-password-on-osx - Though this specifies OSX, it is relevant here as well. Just run through the process using `mysqladmin -u root password 'your password'` AND running the couple of queries they have again. Something's gotta stick, hopefully!

Comment: @amk Edited the question with the output of `show grants`, it thinks I used a password when I did not. Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, something strange

Comment: @MarkOrmston tried everything there, including the `mysqladmin` command, still nothing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Facepalm. It turned out there was a .my.cnf on /root with username and password, and so it was possible to login only with `mysql` when using the root account (that's what I was using). It was created by a Chef recipe (percona was installed via Chef) and I wasn't aware of it.

The hint was to look at the output of `show grants`. Even though I entered no password it still said I entered one, so there must be one somewhere!