# mysql on osx: access denied and can't connect to socket

Tags: mysql, macos

I can't seem to figure out what I have to do in order to install/setup mysql correctly on my new mac.

1.) I installend **mysql** via **homebrew**

2.) I'm able to run `mysql.server start`

[image]

3.) If I try to run `mysql -u root -p` I get this

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I googled and looked through all kind of sources, but can't seem to figure out what to do.

---

Update:

[image]

Update 2:

[image]

Comment: Can you give the o/p of select user,host,password from mysql.user where user='root';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's stop mysqld:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Clean re-installation procedure:

```
brew remove mysql
brew cleanup
brew doctor
```

Backup your database before do next step. Then clean data directory up (to avoid manual run extra step *mysql_install_db* later):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
```

The latest step is to install it again from scratch:

```
brew update
brew install mysql
```

Then run mysqld and try to login to CLI:

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
mysql -u root
```

Answer (score 3):

On the 3rd step run it without `-p` option, which stands for password requirement: Run the command like this `mysql -u root`. If you need to set a password there is another post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474890/383038).

Comment: I updated my question what happens on my end. I tried to set the password to ""

Comment: so you are able to access the database now.

Comment: no, I'm not unfortunately, see my update in the question.

Comment: @matt have you tried setting the password a nonempty string? What happens?

Answer (score 2):

"No" password and password = '' are different things.

For "no" password:

```
mysql -u root
```

For '':

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and then enter empty line when prompted

```
mysql -u root -p root
```

with a space between -p and root means: (1) prompt for password, then (2) `USE root` to establish the default database.

```
mysql -u root -proot
```

without a space says "my password is 'root'".