# Laravel - How to create database tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-migrations

I'm having problems to create database tables.

First of all I create the models:

```
php artisan make:model Company -m
```

Second I update the migration company file, adding the columns that I need

Third I'm going to `phpMyAdmin` and create a new database named test

Fourth I run the command `php artisan migrate` or `php artisan migrate:install` and I have the next error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations)

[PDOException]SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

In `database/config.php` I edit the mysql driver to this:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

And `.env file`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

I also tried to clean cache with `php artisan config:clear` .

Anyone can help me? I don't understand what is the problem.

Thank you

Comment: restart your server and try again

Comment: you dont have password to login to phpmyadmin. remove the password, keep it blank in the env file

Comment: @Exprator phpmyadmin has nothing to do with it, and btw mysql is configured to use a password for that user. Which likely is wrong

Comment: This is mysql password I have to put that. @Exprator

Comment: @Md.Abutaleb , I already do that and doesn't work!

Comment: @DamienPirsy - There is a lack of information, the OP did not state if he is using Windows/Linux and anything related to his MySql installation/configuration. We need to "blind" guess here :)

Comment: I'm using osx! @NorbertBoros

Comment: @user3242861 - Then I will update my answer for OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Your "root" password is incorrect or it may not have required permissions.

```
[PDOException]SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

**Reset "root" password:**

https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords

**Grant "root" user privileges:**

Ubuntu: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-add-a-user-and-grant-root-privileges-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Centos: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-add-a-user-and-grant-root-privileges-on-centos-7/

Then try again :)

Update for the OP ( OSX ):

[Setting the MySQL root user password on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474775/setting-the-mysql-root-user-password-on-os-x)

Comment: I think that it tries to create the migrations table in information_schema... It's normal? @NorbertBoros

Comment: @user3242861 - It should not do that... Does the connection work now ?

Comment: Does this happen because I have only defined the connection after creating the migrations? @NorbertBoros

Comment: @user3242861 - Probably yes, but I see that you have fixed your issue. You should accept my answer for fixing the connectiong :)

Answer (score 0):

in config/database.php file edit the password field to "password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''), and in .env file DB_PASSWORD = keep the field as empty as given here

Comment: How do you know he doesn't use a password ?