# Error on trying to change password in mysql

Tags: mysql, passwords

I forgot the password for mysql, so i was trying to change it using following steps -

1) Stop Mysql server

2)Start server in safe mode by using `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

3) Open mysql command line using `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root`

4) Update password using `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('NewPassword') WHERE User='root';`

But on this step i am getting the following error message -

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('NewPassword') WHERE User='root'' at line 1
```

Can someone tell how to resolve this error?

Comment: which version of mysql you are using?

Answer (score 7):

On 8.0.15 (maybe already before that version) the PASSWORD() function does not work, as mentioned in the comments below. You have to use:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='password' WHERE User='root';
```

[Original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474890)

Answer (score 0):

As problem states clearly, its incorrect syntax.
You should be using official MYSQL procedure to reset password, that includes `create text file with command` and then `restarting the mysqld with text file input with` mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &' command.

Refer official root password reset options for unix [here][1].

[1]https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html