# Mysql error 1064 while changing password

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

While trying to change mysql password by following steps given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) solution, i got the following error-

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('letsrock') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('letsrock') WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost'' at line 1
```

Is there a new syntax for update command in mysql or what? I am using 8.0.12 version.

Comment: did you get the solution? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani This one solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396981/error-on-trying-to-change-password-in-mysql/59059722#59059722

Answer (score 0):

Both 'user' and 'host' are reserved words and cannot be used as identifiers without enclosing them in backticks. Like so:

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('letsrock') 
WHERE `User` = 'root' AND `Host` = 'localhost';
```

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: _Reserved words_, to be specific.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. It would be better to have a (K) and (W) behind each word instead of only an (R) behind 'Reserved Keywords', because 'Reserved Words' also starts with an 'R'.... I changed the answer.

Comment: That didn't work for me despite me copying the code while only replacing the string in `PASSWORD('mystring'). It still throws me` ERROR 1064 (42000): ...` any further ideas?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware This did it for me in the end: `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='letsrock' WHERE User='root';` so, without the `PASSWORD()` 
credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396981/error-on-trying-to-change-password-in-mysql/59059722#59059722