# Why do these approaches not reset my Mysql root password?

Tags: mysql, macos

I have set a root password, but cannot authenticate with it. How can I reset this password?

`~ mysql --version:  mysql  Ver 8.0.13 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew)`

I used [these stackoverflow instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474775/setting-the-mysql-root-user-password-on-os-x) to set a root password and queried the user table to verify the password.

I then tried `mysql -u root -p` and `mysql -u root` and got authentication errors.

Command: `mysql -u root -p` 
Authentication error: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. I am SURE I am using the correct password.

Command:`mysql -u root`
Authentication error: `Error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.

That led me to this [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y/42967789#42967789) and attempted @Lahiru's solution, but got `No such file or directory`.

I found the Mysql documentation and performed the following: (as outlined in [B.6.3.2.3 Resetting Root Password: Generic Instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html))

`mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables`

`Mysql -u root`

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';`

Then I got an error:
`ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

Lastly, using the [Mysql 8.0 documentation: 13.7.1.10 SET PASSWORD Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html) I tried:

`mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables`

`SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = '1111';`

and get error: `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

I can't try to do this while running the server out of safe mode because it doesn't accept the password I set.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Started with --skip-grant-tables, update the mysql.user table with DML.  For MySQL 5.6, we would do:  `UPDATE mysql.user SET password = PASSWORD('mysupersecret') WHERE user = 'root' AND host = 'localhost' ; `  Then restart MySQL server without --skip-grant-tables.

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593 I've tried this multiple times with no luck. Also, in this version of Mysql there is no `password` field. It's `authentication_string`

Comment: "with no luck" is practically useless in describing the observed behavior.  With MySQL 5.7 and later  `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('secretpassword') WHERE user = 'root' AND host = 'localhost' ;`  Does that row exist in mysql.user table?  `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root' AND host = 'localhost'`.

Comment: If i run your first command I get a syntax error. If I remove the `PASSWORD()` method, the user record updates and i query the user record and it verifies the new password in the `authentication_string` field. the i quit sql. stop the the sql server. start again, but not in safe mode. run `mysql -u root -p`, enter the new password and get an authentication error.