# Why is my password not working in mysql? MAC

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I've installed MySQL (8.0.15) via Homebrew and after setting a root password using these steps [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474890/2293679) I've set my password to `root` but when I try to

I get this:
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I tried resetting it via safe mode but still it wont work. I tried checking the `authentication_string` and its this

```
mysql> select authentication_string from user where User = 'root';
+-----------------------+
| authentication_string |
+-----------------------+
| root                  |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a guess that the command `PASSWORD` do not sets the password as it is, but hashes it. Are you sure you don't missed the PASSWORD command from the 
`UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") WHERE User='root';`
Try `SELECT PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD");` it should give you back a hashed value not the string.
Since your database has the "STRING" itself not the hashed value, that might be the problem.