# I messed up my root@localhost for phpadmin and/or mysql. How can I reset the passwords?

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am trying to link a website folder through MAMP in the htdocs directory. But when I go to the localhost:888 to see my website, I'm thrown an access denied for user root. I've tried everything online. My dhb.inc.php has username root's password to an empty string yet it still is giving me this error.

```
Error:
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' 
(using password: NO)
```

dhb.inc.php file permissions:

```
<?php
$dBServername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "loginsystemtut";
```

Comment: Depends on your platform, for ubuntu try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password/31751883

Comment: Im using mac, MAMP PRO

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474775/setting-the-mysql-root-user-password-on-os-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the MySQL root user password on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474775/setting-the-mysql-root-user-password-on-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Open the Mac OS Terminal Application located in your `/Applications/Utilities directory.`
- Enter the following command line:
  `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password [NewPassword]`

For phpMyAdmin change the password in
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`