# Problem connection with MAMP to MySQL after I changed password in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords, connection, mamp

I have a big issue with MAMP.
I changed the password in phpMyAdmin, big error, now, I'm blocked for starting and connecting MySQL.

I tried to resolve this with terminal, with the file php (username and password of phpmyadmin) and even reinstall MAMP but I have the same problem with the copied folder "db".

I just want to get my database back !

Thanks for helping me.

EDIT : I recovered my database with this
https://gist.github.com/premitheme/c45a036e9c6d62662d081c302f51ff20

Comment: phpmyadmin doesn't start ,ysql, it is only a gui for it. so mysql is still runing, what you can chekc by connecting to it with themysql client. so change simply the password back

Comment: I have a real problem, it's impossible to change password on mysql (access denied), I tried everything, and mysql can't connect (in the menu "tools", it's indicated "mysql server not running")

Comment: then reset the password of mysqlm but i am still a bit unsure which password and how you actually changed

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried to change MySQL password (impossible) and PhpMyAdmin (doesn't change anything).

Comment: please try one of these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474775/setting-the-mysql-root-user-password-on-os-x  also when you find problem explain them with the complete error message in your question

Comment: I've tried but, it's ok, I managed to recovery my database with this : https://gist.github.com/premitheme/c45a036e9c6d62662d081c302f51ff20

Thank you 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to recovery my database with this :

[gist.github.com/premitheme/c45a036e9c6d62662d081c302f51ff20](http://gist.github.com/premitheme/c45a036e9c6d62662d081c302f51ff20) Thank you