# How do I reset mysql password in macOS?

Tags: mysql

I have entered the command in the mysql server as in the guide https://dev3lop.com/resetting-mysql-root-password-on-mac-os/

After the UPDATE command I get an error

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('2402') WHERE User = 'root'' at line 1`

WHat do I do to resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474775/setting-the-mysql-root-user-password-on-os-x

Comment: `UPDATE` is not a password reset mechanism, check the official documentation for your MySQL version.